# Inability to capture by Clone prevents some closures from being reusable Fn functions that otherwise could/should be

Tags: rust, closures

Consider the following:

```rust
    use std::ops::Fn;
    
    fn require_picky_callback( cb : impl Fn() -> () + 'static) { }
    
    fn main() {
        let s = String::from("Rust");
        ...
        let s_copy = s.clone();
        let cb = move || {
            s_copy;
        };
        require_picky_callback(cb);
    
    }
```

If String in this example were replaced with a Copy-able type such as int, this example would compile. Unfortunately since capture by Clone is not possible, the only workaround is to create a copy outside the closure and move it in, but then the closure is no longer a pure function Fn, and instead a FnOnce. Is there any workaround such that my closure remains a Fn but also captures the String? This seems like it should be possible in principal.

Note that [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2407) where the inability to clone into closure issue is discussed has a similar example, but less restrictive since the `thread::spawn` function does not require `Fn`

Comment: One solution I've come up with is to convert the String into an array of char, which implements Copy, and then convert that back to String inside the closure. That seems hideous though.

Comment: This is not an issue with clone, if you used `s` directly you'd have the same problem. The problem is *moving* the captured value from within the closure. Your stubbed `s_copy;` statement causes a move *out* of `s_copy` and therefore `cb` only implements `FnOnce`. If you replaced it with something that doesn't cause a move, like `s_copy.len();`, then it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just make a copy for each invocation and thus don't move the `String` out of the closure:

```rust
fn require_picky_callback(_cb: impl Fn() -> () + 'static) {}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Rust");
    let cb = move || {
        let s = s.clone();
        drop(s);
    };
    require_picky_callback(cb);
}
```

This works because while `s` is captured by the closure, but because `clone` only requires a reference it's never moved out of.

The `drop` is only there to show we can do anything we want with the new `s` it's not required at all.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e707f8f7cb0f4275fff21bd9fb368e2b)

Comment: oh boy thats painfully obvious in hindsight. Thanks. What are the exact semantics at play here though? To get `s` into the closure to take a clone of doesn't a stack reference exist that violates the `static'` lifetime requirement of `require_picky_callback`? Also why is calling drop necessary?

Comment: @AshwinGupta Calling `drop` is not necessary.